# Не работают медиа запросы без !important

Tags: html, css, sass, media-queries

Использую отдельный файл `media.sass` для написания медиа-запросов. Но ничего не работает без `!important`. Как только его прописываю для каждого параметра, всё начинает работать чётко, по разрешениям. Без него — пусто, основные стили перебиваются. В чём проблема?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px)
.call 
    ul
        li
            span
                font-size: em(15px) 
        li:last-child 
            padding-left: 10px
            padding-top: 14px
.prem
    h3
        font-size: em(15px)
```

Comment: media.sass - должен быть подключен после основных стилей

Answer (score 2):

В том, что ты не в том порядке подключаешь файлы. Надо сначала обычный, а потом media.