# Медиа-запросы не работают без !important

Tags: css, вёрстка, media-queries

Здравствуйте! Столкнулась с такой странностью, при верстке с определенного момента медиа-запросы перестали работать без !important.

Не понимаю в чем причина и как этого избежать.

Привожу часть CSS кода

```
html {
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
.container {
    margin-top: 150px;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: center;
-webkit-justify-content: center;
    align-content: space-between;
-webkit-align-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
-webkit-align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
-webkit-flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
  margin-top: 110px;
}
}

/* iPhone 6 Plus */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 414px) 
and (max-device-width : 736px) {
  .container {
  margin-top: 120px !important;
}
}
```

В коде видно, что первый медиа-запрос сработал обычно, во втором для 414px уже пришлось применять !important.

В чем может быть причина и как с этим справиться?

Comment: 1. [mcve] 2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/608283/178988

Answer (score 5):

Здравствуйте!
А каким образом тестируете? В каких браузерах не работает как надо?

Я проверила Ваш код у себя в браузерах на ноутбуке (последние версии Chrome и Firefox) - все ОК и без !important.

В IE11 заработает, только если:

- убрать в последнем правиле only,
- вместо min-device-width и
  max-device-width написать min-width и max-width.

Я не профи, но вижу, что копать нужно в сторону этих двух моментов.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, я не очень поняла почему так было. Убрала все only и после этого заработало без !important. min-device-width и max-device-width оставила без изменений.

Answer (score 1):

Добавляйте медиа-запросы в конце `css` файла.

Comment: я так и делаю, они стоят в конце

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так

```
@media screen 
and (min-width: 740px)
and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .container {
  margin-top: 110px;
}
}
```

Comment: спасибо,но все-равно не работает без !important